# Have a button scroll along with View

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, tableview

I have a button that I created programmatically and I placed on top of my UITableViewController. I'm able to do it fine, my problem its when I scroll I want the button to go along the view and be fixed on that position.

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80, 210, 160, 40);
[button setTitle:@"Holaa" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view insertSubview:button aboveSubview:self.tableView];
```

I tried using implementation scrollViewDidScroll, but I'm unable to recalculate on what position should the button be at that time.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want the button to scroll to once the scroll ends? Does it scroll with one of the cells?

Comment: On the same position but always visible.

Comment: does the button move when the user scrolls the table? your question is pretty confusing. One place you are saying it is always in the same position and in the orig question you are saying that you want it to go along with the view.  Which one is it? you will need to explain the exact req corectly.

Comment: I want it to be like the Assistive Touch circle, that it will be always in one position, does not matter if you are scrolling.

Comment: If I understand you correctly now, you want to attach a UIPanGestureRecognizer to the button and then handle the movement in the handlePan method. I am addign an answer with that. You can also add some dynamic behaviors for the button movement if needed. Lmk and i will add that as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the scrollview's contentOffset to calculate position.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the button as headerview  for the tableview

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 //Return your button
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 [button setTitle:@"Holaa" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Comment: The problem with this its that I don't want it on top of the table.

Answer (score 0):

In the viewDidLoad you can attach the pan gesture like this:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanBehavior:)];
panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self.touchButton addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Then add the handlePanBehavior function as follows:

```
- (void)handlePanBehavior:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture {
    CGRect buttonFrame = self.touchButton.frame;
    CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:panGesture.view];

    buttonFrame.origin.x += translation.x;
    buttonFrame.origin.y += translation.y;

    [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:panGesture.view];
    self.touchButton.frame = buttonFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the button on the table view. Add it by below way:

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Just make sure that `tableView` is added before you add the button to `self.view`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect frame = button.frame;
    frame.origin.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x + 80;
    frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + 210;
    [button setFrame:frame];
}
```